# Upload code files with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, r, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, paperclip-validation

What should be the `validates_attachment_content_type` configuration in order to be able to upload code files. In my case I want to upload .R files.

I want to do something like this:

```
class RFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :r, url: "/system/:attachment/:id/:basename.:extension"
  validates_attachment_content_type :r, content_type: 'text/r'
end
```

Do I have to define a mime type? How should I do that?

**EDIT:**

With this code, using `text/plain`:

```
class RFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :r, url: "/system/:attachment/:id/:basename.:extension"
  validates_attachment_content_type :r, content_type: 'text/plain'
end
```

I get the following errors:

```
R has contents that are not what they are reported to be
R is invalid
R content type is invalid
```

I looked at this list of mime types

http://hul.harvard.edu/ois/systems/wax/wax-public-help/mimetypes.htm

But I don't find the one for .R files. But when executing this command:

```
file --mime-type compare_datasets.R
```

I get this result:

```
compare_datasets.R: text/plain
```

Why the `text/plain` does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to be able to get it working by doing this in the mime type initializer:

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = {r: "text/plain"}
```

And this in the model:

```
class RFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :r, url: "/system/:attachment/:id/:basename.:extension"
  validates_attachment_file_name :r, matches: [/r\Z/, /R\Z/]
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :r
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For code files you can use `text/plain` MIME type.

```
validates_attachment_content_type :r, :content_type => 'text/plain'
```

a number of such file endings can be found [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/)

Comment: I tried with text/plain but I'm still not able to upload the file. I edited the question with the code and errors.

Comment: Try with this `text/x-r`mime type